# how to get sequential set of rows from azure tables ?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

My client requests upto an unknow number of items and requires I deliver the batch with sequaltial ids (no fragmentation). Each item has an id. I can store multible items in a row but that number is not enough so I need to get subsequent rows as well. Considering I will have concurent calls, how can I do this with azure tables ?

Comment: Are you able to get creative?  Like fill the holes in sequence later? or re-arrange id's later?

Comment: I can't quite understand what's being asked, but table storage does support range requests on row keys (get row X through row Y).

Comment: Sorry , I missed an important part. I can give an item to only one client. So I need to query to decide on rows  then delete them from table and I want those rows to be sequential and this deletion to be atomic.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870327/auto-increment-on-azure-table-storage - It sounds a lot like what you have described

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx for more information about batch requests against table storage. As for concurrency, you can take advantage of the If-Match header. Both update and delete operations support If-Match. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179427 for more information. If those don’t help, it would be better if you can provide more information, we will try our best to provide further suggestions for you.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.